# Images Not Running From JAR (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I'm trying to load a single JLabel set with an ImageIcon for display. It works fine when I compile it within my IDE, but when I export the image will not show up. Here's the code I'm using to set the image.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("test.png");
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
```

I know I asked a question along the same lines as this last time, so I tried "getClass().getResource(...)", but that's been throwing an error at me. What do I need to do with this JLabel to get that image to show even when I export? I'd like the image to be part of the JAR package, as this entire thing is supposed to be something of a surprise.

Comment: @daniechiu: why dont you stick to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870517/exporting-images-with-jar-in-eclipse-java

Comment: @Harry, then mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Harry, it is one of the "close" options.

Comment: @Thorbjorn: but i can not see a **close** option. where is it located?

Comment: @Harry, should be right under the question tags.  If you don't see it, you probably have too low a reputation.

Comment: @Thorbjorn: i cant see the link so might be i dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `test.png` is not in the `classpath` of your application.  Assuming it is a `jar`, the image may be in a subfolder, say, `image`, in which case, you would need to specify the following

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image/test.png");
```

If this is not the case, please edit the question and specify the layout of the jar - how the contents, especially the images are organized therein.

Comment: So within my project folder I have a folder named "src" and a folder named "img". The image I want to use is located within img, all the source classes are located in "src". I'm finding that "test.png" and "img/test.png" work interchangeably in my IDE, but neither works in the exported JAR.

Comment: that is incorrect.  new ImageIcon("..") loads from a _file_, not the classpath.